# Function inside a function (Reference)

Tags: c, function, reference

I just starting  to learn the C language, I've got this function to explain but I really don't understand it.

```
int uknown(int a, int b)
    {
        if  (b == 1) return a;
        else return a + uknown(a, b - 1);
    }
```

When i use the function with a printf command for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf ("Value = %i", uknown(3,4));
    system("pause");
}
```

I get a return value of 12. But I'm struggling to understand how the calculation was made.

Comment: What aspect are you uncertain about? Is it about the embedment of a function within the `printf`? Or are you uncertain about how recursion works in this case (independent of the `printf`)?

Comment: Step through it with a debugger -- or, if you don't know how to do that, insert a couple of `printf`s in the `uknown` function.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I actually cant get how the "uknown" function works, how come i get 12 as return value. Independent of the printf.

Comment: The term that you should look up is "recursion".

Comment: **recursion** : [ri-kur-zhuhn] - See recursion.

Comment: I think my answer makes more sense as a comment. Basically, the function is doing multiplication, the "long" way. ie: uknown(3,4) is 3+3+3+3.  unknown(100,2) is 100+100;

Comment: Here is the function expressed using an iterator rather than using recursion: `int uknownIter(int a, int b){int output = 0;for(; b >= 1; b--){output = output + a;}return output;}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) method to multiply two integers by addition. The function calls recursively as

```
uknown(3,4) calls (since b != 1)
      uknown(3,3) calls (since b != 1)
            uknown(3,2) calls (since b != 1) 
                  uknown(3,1) returns 3 to uknown(3,2) (since b == 1)
            uknown(3,2) returns 3 + 3 = 6 to uknown(3,3) 
      uknown(3,3)  returns 3 + 6 = 9 to uknown(3,4) 
uknown(3,4)  returns 3 + 9 = 12 to printf in main
```

Answer (score 2):

Statement `return a + uknown(a, b - 1);` returns value as below steps,

```
 3 + unknown(3, 3);
 3 + 3 + unknown(3, 2);
 3 + 3 + 3 + unknown(3, 1);
 3 + 3 + 3 + 3; // The last 3 is because of statement if  (b == 1) return a;
 = 12
```